# Some doubts about Java Configuration of the Spring Application Context (dependency injection)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

I am studying for Spring Core certification.

I know that in Spring I can configure the **dependency injection** using 3 way:

1. **Java Configuration**
2. **Classes annotations**
3. **XML Configuration**

I have some doubt related to how to use the first kind of dependency injection configuration.

For example I have something like this:

1) A class named **TransferServiceImpl**:

```
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    public TransferServiceImpl(AccountRepository ar) {
        this.accountRepository = ar;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

This class contain the **TransferServiceImpl()** constructor  that take an **AccountRepository** object as input paramether, so **AccountRepository** is a dependency that have to be injected into **TransferServiceImpl()**.

2) This is the implementation of the previous **AccountRepository** class:

```
public class JdbcAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {
    public JdbcAccountRepository(DataSource ds) {
        this.dataSource = ds;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

So the constructor of this class thake a **DataSource** object that have to be injected into the JdbcAccountRepository class.

Then I have a **configurations class** that contains the dependency injection configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig{

    @Bean public TransferService transferService(){
        return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository());
    }

    @Bean public AccountRepository accountRepository(){
        return JdbcAccountRepository(dataSoruce());
    }

    @Bean public DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ...................................
        ...................................
        ...................................
    }
}
```

So it seems to me that it work in the following way:

I have my 2 implemented **beans** named **TransferServiceImpl** and  **JdbcAccountRepository** and the **configuration class** named **ApplicationConfig**.

Into the configuration class I say that when someone ask to the factory to create a **TransferService** object it automatically build its implementation **TransferServiceImpl** creating and injecting automatically a **JdbcAccountRepository** into the **TransferServiceImpl** constructor.

In the same way when a **JdbcAccountRepository** is created it is injected a **DataSource** object into its constructor.

Is it right?

If it is right I have the following doubts:

1) Into the **ApplicationConfig** class I also declare the **DataSource** bean but I don't implement this class. Is it a class provided by Spring and I have only to set its properties values?

2) When are created the bean definied into the **ApplicationConfig** class? At the application startup? I think that, in the previous example, if I annotate a constructor using **@Bean** it is created as singleton at the application startup. Is it right or am I missing something?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Into the ApplicationConfig class I also declare the DataSource bean
>   but I don't implement this class. Is it a class provided by Spring and
>   I have only to set its properties values?

Yes. There are a number of `DataSource` implementations provided by Spring. For example: `DriverManagerDataSource`, `SingleConnectionDataSource`, and more.

> 2) When are created the bean definied into the ApplicationConfig
>   class? At the application startup? I think that, in the previous
>   example, if I annotate a constructor using @Bean it is created as
>   singleton at the application startup. Is it right or am I missing
>   something?

By default beans are created when Spring container is instantiated (usually at startup if the app is wired as such). You can change this behavior, however, by using the `@Lazy` annotation where the bean will only be created when explicitly requested.

```
@Bean @Lazy public TransferService transferService(){
    return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository());
}
```